# Не редактируется код в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

За место обычного текстового курсора, появляется выделенное поле. Удалять код можно, а вот писать его не получается (я нажимаю на клавиатуру, но никакого текста не добавляется

[image: Красным обведено то, что появляется за место текстового курсора]

Comment: Попробуйте нажать кнопку `insert` на клавиатуре

Comment: Либо у вас включен vim-mode. Посмотрите в плагинах, установлен ли плагин `IdeaVim`

Comment: Перезапустите ide

Answer (score 0):

Удалил плагин  *IdeaVim*, всё заработало.